# Change Icon of a raised Exception in Delphi

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-2007

In our application we have created several Exceptions classes for all our needs. But now the problem is, that the raised Exception Dialog always is MessageType `mtError` and of course shows the `mtError`-Icon.
For a few of our Exceptions i would prefer a *less agressive* Icon/MessageType, for example MessageType `mtInformation`.

Is there any way to change the Icon directly in the Exceptionclass without raising and catching it again with `try...except` on each occurence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to customise the top level exception handler.

Write an event handler and attach it to `Application.OnException`. You can then handle particular exceptions any way you like.

The event handler will look like this:

```
procedure TMainForm.ApplicationException(Sender: TObject; E: Exception); 
begin   
  if E is EMyException then
    ShowExpectedMessageBox(E)
  else
    Application.ShowException(E);
end;
```

Obviously you have to write the code for `ShowExpectedMessageBox`. This can show a message box using whatever icon you prefer.

The [OnException](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnException) event is called when an unhandled exception reaches the message loop. If you don't have an event handler, the framework calls `Application.ShowException`. Which is what you should do for those exceptions that do not get your special treatment.